# Documentation about JMX and WebSphere

Tags: java, websphere, jmx, websphere-8, java-ee-7

At first i know it exist one official documantion about WebSphere APi:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc%2Fweb%2Fapidocs%2Fcom%2Fibm%2Fwebsphere%2Fmanagement%2FAdminClient.html

But that isnt a good one. It explains very few things and does help me just a little.

Iam searching for a good book or good paper wich explain all function, packeg, classes in a good way.

Can anybody help me?

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Infocentre (the link you provided), the APIs are usually provided in the References subsection, for each product. I don't think you'll find a more complete list than that anywhere else.

If you mean resources on WebSphere Application Server, you can try searching for that on IBM Redbooks, e.g.:
http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg247957.pdf

Devworks also has quite a few papers explaining concepts/providing examples for IBM products.
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/

Answer (score 0):

Additionally i definition for MBeans in WAS 8.x !
Does anybody know ?

Something like this : http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-development/websphere/0131446045/websphere-version-5-run-time-mbeans/app02lev1sec1

This Page isnt aktual.

I cant find it on the official documentation.

Thanks